# Cocoa - problem with this code using NSBundle

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsimage, nsbundle

It was suggested that I use this line of code to call an image from my resources folder/project bundle. I also see it being used exactly like this on many different website tutorials.

```
NSBundle *mb=[NSBundle mainBundle];


NSString *fp=[mb pathForResource:@"topimage" ofType:@"PNG"];


NSImage *image=[NSImage initWithContentsOfFile:fp];
```

HOWEVER, I am receiving the following warning:

> NSImage may not respond to +initWithContentsOfFile+

The documentation for NSImage shows that initWithContentsOfFile is in fact a method that should work. What might I be missing here?

Comment: It's "Mac" not "MAC" – two very different topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an `+alloc`

```
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fp];
```

You can also use `+imageNamed:`, which fetches images from your main bundle.

```
NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"topImage.png"];
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what the issue was

Answer (score 4):

`initWithContentsOfFile:` is an instance method, but you're sending that message to the NSImage class. You need to send it to an instance—specifically, a freshly-allocated instance.

That's where `alloc` comes in. It's a class method that allocates an instance, which you then immediately send the `init…` message (as Darren showed).

Don't forget to release the instance when you're done with it. I generally autorelease the instance immediately after initing it; then, Cocoa will release the instance for me at an appropriate time. See the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) for more information.