# Cant access NSImage object or not able "import NSImage.h"

Tags: ios, nsimage

Well I am confused because should be a no brainer.

In Xcode 5 I start a new iphone project.
In ViewDidLoad I begin typing:

NSImage *image ...

Actually at the point of "NSI" ... the NSImage is not available. 
I see many other options like NSInteger etc...

So from the start I cant create a NSImage object.

Ok so I look at documentation for NSImage and it clearly says object is declared in both following packages (why are there 2 declarations and which one should I use)

```
Declared in NSGraphics.h
NSImage.h
```

but I am not allowed to import any of these packages.I just get red line next to it when I try to do that.

So if I am not allowed to import this package ... why does the documentation give me information about the package that it is in. I am sure I should be able to use it ??

So what daft thing am I doing ?

Answer (score 4):

NSImage.h is an OS X class. You should be using UIImage, NSImage's iOS equivalent. This can get confusing considering a lot of the "NS" prefixed names are shared between iOS and OS X, but an easy way to determine what is available is to have a look at the iOS class references for [Foundation.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroFoundation.html) or [UIKit.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html).

You can also expand the headers group in the frameworks group in Xcode's file inspector to see what headers are available to you.

Comment: so trying to read an image from a bundle like so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659407/cocoa-problem-with-this-code-using-nsbundle there are lots of example of NSImage ? What is the difference why can they use it ?

Comment: That question is about OS X development.

Comment: Many thanks !! I thought I was going mad for a second :) (I am obviously still learning ios development)

Comment: @drlobo Glad to hear this helped! Don't forget to mark as correct :)